# Url Rewriting Magento

Tags: magento

I want to use manufacture name ,category name and manufacture part no in my product url

example 
my current url is

http://192.168.1.17/lampslightingandmore_magento/product-name.html

want to change to
http://192.168.1.17/lampslightingandmore_magento/category-manufacture-partno.html

please help
thanks

Comment: It would help if your links would actually work outside of you own network... (IP address 192.168.1.something is local network)

Answer (score 0):

Go to: **Catalog -> Manage Products** and edit a product, under **General** you will find **"URL key"**, change it for your personal needs.

You can also change the url rewrites by following this example:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/welcome_to_the_magento_user_s_guide/chapter_3#url_rewrites